# When adding Google tag script in WordPress site, functionality not working

Tags: google-tag-manager

When I add Google Tag Manager script in my WordPress website, user login, checkout functionalities facing issue. I tried with child theme as well as added script using plugins (google-tag-manage, insert-headers-and-footers), but issue is there.

When we remove tag manager code, site working fine. I am using WordPress version 5.3.2.

When adding a dummy container id in the script, then all functionalities are working. If give our own container id, only facing problem

Site URL: http://43o.f42.myftpupload.com

Answer (score 1):

The script portion of the GTM container code is in the body of the page just before the closing `</header>` tag.

It needs to be installed in the `<head></head>` section of the site.

If you also choose use the optional noscript tag portion of the GTM container code, then the noscript tag should be immediately following the opening `<body>` tag.